# A problem with the emulator in Android Studio. Small screen and the app won't run

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I'm having an issue with my emulator. It won't run my app. The app is working fine on an actual phone. I've already looked at some others and tried a few things but it just isn't working.

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p68Co.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PsJL.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0EJy.png)

What's with the minus points instead of answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

Got negative votes but no answer.

Found a solution for the screen size problem [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102445/my-emulator-screen-is-wrong):

Find "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64"
Right click "the qemu-system… .exe" you are using
Properties->Compatibility:Change high dpi Setting to be overwritten by System.